# Designing a chat bubble for RTL and LTR locales in android

Tags: android, xml, textview, right-to-left

I am trying to use "Actor" Open Source Messenger application for android, but it has a bug in displaying the chat bubbles for RTL languages. The bubbles displayed for English text and RTL language text are provided [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNSs8.png).

I want it to be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVFtO.png), as it is in messengers like "Whatsapp".

This is the xml file for the bubble view:

```
<im.actor.sdk.controllers.conversation.view.BubbleContainer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true">

<im.actor.sdk.controllers.conversation.view.BubbleTextContainer
    android:id="@+id/fl_bubble"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:duplicateParentState="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <im.actor.sdk.view.TintImageView
            android:id="@+id/stateIcon"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</im.actor.sdk.controllers.conversation.view.BubbleTextContainer>
```

I tried to change the "left" and "right" gravity parameters to "start" and "end" but it didn't work.

How should I change this layout file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those bubble measurements are done in "BubbleTextContainer" class.
You should do some changes there. Seeing the code, I guess you would understand. To be more specific, there are *fullContentH* and *fullContentW* variables in *onMeasure* method. Change them there due to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have rtlSupport set as true for application tag in manifest.

Comment: Still no change ! :(